# Enumerating text (ranges) vertically and horizontally

Tags: c#, strings, iterator

I'm writing a parser and I need to iterate through text vertically (down to bottom) and horizontally (left to right).

This alone would be easy but some text parts need to be *rescanned* by another parser and for this I need to reiterate over *random* lines or a text range.

I wrote two *enumerators*.

One for enumerating all lines or only some of them:

```
internal class LineEnumerator
{
    private const int IndexOutOfRange = -1;

    public LineEnumerator(IReadOnlyList<string> lines) : this(lines, null) { }

    public LineEnumerator(IReadOnlyList<string> lines, IReadOnlyList<int> lineNumbers)
    {
        Lines = lines;
        Index = -1;
        LineNumbers = lineNumbers;
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<string> Lines { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<int> LineNumbers { get; }
    public int Index { get; private set; }
    public bool IsIndexInRange => Index > IndexOutOfRange && Index < (LineNumbers?.Count ?? Lines.Count);
    public int LineNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (!IsIndexInRange) { return IndexOutOfRange; }
            return LineNumbers?[Index] ?? Index;
        }
    }
    public string Current => IsIndexInRange ? Lines[LineNumber] : null;

    public CharEnumerator Chars => IsIndexInRange ? new CharEnumerator(Current) : null;

    public bool MoveNext() => ++Index < (LineNumbers?.Count ?? Lines.Count);
}
```

and another one for enumerating chars or only a particular range:

```
internal class CharEnumerator
{
    private const int IndexOutOfRange = -1;

    public CharEnumerator(string line) : this(line, 0, line.Length) { }

    public CharEnumerator(string line, int index0, int length)
    {
        Line = line;
        Index0 = index0;
        Length = length;
        Index = IndexOutOfRange;
    }

    public string Line { get; }
    public int Index0 { get; }
    public int Length { get; }
    public int Counter { get; private set; }
    public int Index { get; private set; }
    public bool IsIndexInRange => Index >= Index0 && Counter <= Length;
    public char Current => IsIndexInRange ? Line[Index] : '\0';

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (!IsIndexInRange)
        {
            Index = Index0;
            Counter++;
            return true;
        }
        Index++;
        Counter++;
        return (Counter <= Length);
    }
}
```

---

They shouldn't just enumerate the text but also keep track of where they are so that I can throw exceptions with *exact* location if something goes wrong thus the line enumerator needs to work with *real* indexes even for a range. The same applies to the char enumerator.

I feel like the enumerators violate SRP *(single responsibility principle)* and I should create two more enumerators for enumerating a range of lines or a range of characters. Is this necessary or would you leave it like that?

---

**Examples**

```
var lines = new[] { "foo", "bar", "baz", "qux" };
var lineEnumerator = new LineEnumerator(lines);
while (lineEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(lineEnumerator.Current);
}
```

> foo bar baz qux

```
Console.WriteLine();
var lineRangeEnumerator = new LineEnumerator(lines, new[] { 1, 3 });
while (lineRangeEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(lineRangeEnumerator.Current);
}
```

> bar qux

```
Console.WriteLine();
var line = "foo bar baz";
var charEnumerator = new CharEnumerator(line);
while (charEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(charEnumerator.Current);
}
```

> f o o   b a r   b a z

```
Console.WriteLine();
var charRangeEnumerator = new CharEnumerator(line, 4, 3);
while (charRangeEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(charRangeEnumerator.Current);
}
```

> b a r

Comment: What exactly are you parsing? Does this interface with excel or something else?

Comment: @pacmaninbw no, it doesn't interface with excel. I'm parsing my own template format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with standard `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable`, so it could be consumed as:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var template = new Template("foo", "bar", "baz", "qux");

        foreach (var row in template)
            Console.WriteLine(row.Text);

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (var row in template.Select(1, 3))
            Console.WriteLine(row.Text);

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (var row in template.Select(0))
            foreach (var column in row)
                Console.WriteLine(column.Text);

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (var row in template.Select(0))
            foreach (var column in row.Range(0,3))
                Console.WriteLine(column.Text);
    }
```

Where `Select` allows to subset by indecies provided, while `Range` is working in terms of `start` and `count`. `Row` and `Column` objects have `Index` (current selection) and `Indecies` (allowed to be selected) properties:

```
public class Template : IEnumerable<Row>
{
    public Template(params string[] lines)
    {
        Lines = lines;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Row> Range(int start, int count) => Select(Enumerable.Range(start, count));
    public IEnumerable<Row> Select(params int[] indecies) => Select(indecies as IEnumerable<int>);
    public IEnumerable<Row> Select(IEnumerable<int> indecies)
    {
        foreach (var index in indecies)
            yield return new Row(Lines.ElementAtOrDefault(index), index, indecies);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Row> GetEnumerator() => Range(0, Lines.Length).GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    string[] Lines { get; }
}
```

And:

```
public struct Row : IEnumerable<Column>
{
    public Row(string text, int index, IEnumerable<int> indecies)
    {
        Text = text;
        Index = index;
        Indecies = indecies;
    }

    public string Text { get; }
    public int Index { get; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Indecies { get; }

    public IEnumerable<Column> Range(int start, int count) => Select(Enumerable.Range(start, count));
    public IEnumerable<Column> Select(params int[] indecies) => Select(indecies as IEnumerable<int>);
    public IEnumerable<Column> Select(IEnumerable<int> indecies)
    {
        foreach (var index in indecies)
            yield return new Column(Text.ElementAtOrDefault(index), index, indecies);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Column> GetEnumerator() => Range(0, Text.Length).GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

And:

```
public struct Column
{
    public Column(char text, int index, IEnumerable<int> indecies)
    {
        Text = text;
        Index = index;
        Indecies = indecies;
    }

    public char Text { get; }
    public int Index { get; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Indecies { get; }
}
```

Comment: Damn! This is agian a nice aproach ;-D

Comment: I'll change the `ElementAtOrDefault` into `return indecies.Select(index => new Row(Lines[index], index, indecies));` because it will definitely exist and if not, this means I made a mistake somewhere else and this will allow me to spot the bug soon enough.

Comment: Just in case - `ElementAt` and `ElementAtDefault` are smart enough to check actual data type interfaces and consume `IList<T>[index]` if implemented.

Comment: BTW it's "indices" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most of my comments have been mentioned by @Dmitry Nogin. In addition

- In your `LineEnumerator` constructor, I don't see the reason why you can't assign `IndexOutOfRange` to `Index` just like you've done in `CharEnumerator` constructor
- Use `readonly` keyword in place of `get{..}`  since the values for the below fields are assigned only through the `constructor`

```js
public  readonly string Line;
public readonly int Index0;
public readonly int Length;
```

- I don't think you should be passing length as a parameter because you could always retrieve the value from `line.Length`. A potential problem would be if the user assigned `-1` to `Length` e.g 
  `var charEnumerator = new CharEnumerator(line,2,-1);`.

> This line of code will never evaluate to `true`
>      `public bool IsIndexInRange => Index >= Index0 && Counter <= Length;`

- To be honest, when I saw your two enumerators I expected the classes to implement `IEnumerator<T>, IEnumerator` interfaces as these interfaces contain members such as `MoveNext, Current and Reset()` which you have manually defined here.
- When I passed in these values 
  `var charEnumerator = new CharEnumerator(line,2,11);`
  I can't extract the character at that position except when I do this

```js
charEnumerator.MoveNext();
Console.WriteLine(charEnumerator.Current);
```

In the ideal scenario  would have expected the `charEnumerator` to have a functionality of returning the item rather than doing these two steps above.

- Just like the other reviewer has suggested using a `struct` in the scenario is a good approach. I would have done the same myself
- When you use **IReadOnlyList**, it's possible the second constructor can be called with `null, null` as they are valid inputs. Calling any member properties will result in  `System.NullReferenceException`

```html
   var lineEnumerator = new LineEnumerator(null, null);
     Console.WriteLine(lineEnumerator.IsIndexInRange);
```

This should be taken into consideration.

I will be back for the `LineEnumerator` review later today . Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the review ;-) I agree with you on some points but on others not, I will comment on the latter... _Use `readonly` keyword_ I wanted all members to be properties because I thougt it might be better like that, just a prejudice ;-] _passing length as a parameter_ - this is a vital feature because I sometimes need only a part of the string at an exact position. _`IsIndexInRange`_ - this is indeed true when the enumerator is in the allowed range, the last `MoveNext` will exceed the count and make if false. _`CharEnumerator(line,2,11);`_ - this is a vital feature too ;-)

Comment: _it's possible the second constructor can be called with null, null_ - theoretically yes but this would be huge bug in the core as there musn't be any nulls ever (as long as the index/length calculations are fine) ;-] I agree with all other points and I changed it to Dimitri's solution. It now works like a charm. I admit, mine was broken in so many places and extremely difficult to use in some places.

Comment: To be honest , using readonly is a matter of style @t3chb0t .